# vb.net buttonless delete in gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datagridview

i am trying to delete a record in my database via datagridview by just pressing the delete key but its giving me error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.". here is my code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_UserDeletedRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.UserDeletedRow

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim deleterows As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value
        Dim sqlquery As String = "delete from tblname where ID = " & deleterows & ";"
        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand

        With sqlcommand
            .CommandText = sqlquery
            .Connection = conn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: first, you are looping thru ALL rows and not testing if this row is a selected row.  Next, when you delete a row, the basis of your For/Next loop changes so that if it deletes ANY rows, the ACTUAL row count will be LESS than the value it started with resulting in the error.  VB creates a temp variable for `DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1` such as `28`, when you delete, there are no longer that many to loop thru.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the problem lies with "DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1"
it may not be performing the -1 calculation...

try (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use a loop to delete the rows, try going backwards through your rows (i.e. start at the last row and work your way back, instead of starting at the front and working forward).

For what you are describing, it might work better to leave the loop out all together (using your own code) :

```
 Dim deleterows As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value
 Dim sqlquery As String = "delete from tblname where ID = " & deleterows & ";"
 Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand

 With sqlcommand
     .CommandText = sqlquery
     .Connection = conn
     .ExecuteNonQuery()
 End With
```